# CVS history....can't get it work

Tags: cvs

An really embarrassing question: I have specified my CVS root, and within
this CVS root I have a repository, let call it REP. Within REP, I have
a file TEST.TXT where I wanna see all revisions of it. Unfortunately, 
I cant get this work, i tried the following:

```
cvs history TEST.TXT
cvs history /REP/TEST.TXT
cvs history REP/TEST.TXT
```

Anyone an idea what I am doing wrong? Do i miss a command that tells CVS which repository
I am referring to?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the symptom you are seeing when you try to use the "cvs history" command?  What is the setting of your CVSROOT environment variable?

Comment: BTW `cvs history` is primarily a machine-readable text dump of information that's hard to read by a human.  Are you sure you want that, and not `cvs log`, which provides history in human-understandable form?

Answer (score 1):

I vaguely remember cvs... :-)

The usual way to tell cvs which repository you are using is with the `CVSROOT` environment variable. If the repository is on localhost then this can just be a full pathname.

The usual way to get revision history on a file is not to examine the repository-wide history file, but rather it is to run the `cvs log` command which will extract the rcs revision information for a given file or subtree.

Example:

```
$ echo $CVSROOT
/home/ross/cvs
$ cvs log q.rb

RCS file: /home/ross/cvs/R3/q.rb,v
Working file: q.rb
head: 1.1
branch: 1.1.1
locks: strict
access list:
symbolic names:
    R1: 1.1.1.1
    ROSS: 1.1.1
keyword substitution: kv
total revisions: 2; selected revisions: 2
description:
----------------------------
revision 1.1
date: 2009-11-12 10:36:27 -0800;  author: ross;  state: Exp;  commitid: MlYKy8V908Lmagbu;
branches:  1.1.1;
Initial revision
----------------------------
revision 1.1.1.1
date: 2009-11-12 10:36:27 -0800;  author: ross;  state: Exp;  lines: +0 -0;  commitid: MlYKy8V908Lmagbu;
initial import
=============================================================================
```